# CSS animations stop working when XML file is transformed in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a page, with multiple animations on it. If I save it as an html file and run it in a browser, it works as it should, but has no information as I have no imported the xml document. When I add in my xml, by using xslt transformation, and save it as xsl not html, the animations will no longer run, and I'm lost as to why this is happening.

I use

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="blog.xsl" ?>
```

to connect my xml file with the xslt, and then in xml use

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>

</html>
```

Any help as to why it's not working as xslt but is as html would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE blog SYSTEM "blog.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="blog.xsl"?>
<blog>

<blogPost>
    <postTitle> First Test Post </postTitle>
    <postText> This is a test post </postText>
    <postImage></postImage>
    <postQuote> Happiness can be found even in the darkest of times if one only remembers to turn on the light </postQuote>
    <postLink> www.pandora.net </postLink>
    <postAudio></postAudio>
    <postVideo></postVideo>
    <postChat></postChat>
    <postDate> 12th June </postDate>
    <postTags> FirstPost New </postTags>
</blogPost>

<blogPost>
    <postTitle> Post Two </postTitle>
    <postText> This is a another test post </postText>
    <postImage></postImage>
    <postQuote> Never let the fear of striking out keep you from
    playing the game</postQuote>
    <postLink> www.surfdome.com </postLink>
    <postAudio></postAudio>
    <postVideo></postVideo>
    <postChat></postChat>
    <postDate> 12th June </postDate>
    <postTags> FirstPost New </postTags>
</blogPost>
</blog>
```

Comment: Consider to provide a URL to a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: We need clearly more details to help. But I'm not sure to understand well, what you tried. You have an HTML file, saved as .html, inside it you have the processing instruction <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="blog.xsl" ?>, then you have a blog.xsl to add data in your html, is that right ? Then, in your xsl, you should add the processing instruction for css, maybe that's what you're missing... without more, that's all I can do.

Comment: @EricS I have an XML file with the data in, which connects to my XSL file with the html info in and templates etc, and then my external CSS file too. Just loading up to show more code, can't do in jsfiddle as not sure how to add xml to it? I believe it's the xml that's causing the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pr9aj0tp/ is the CSS and XSL, which clearly the animations are working. When adding the XML which I've put some of in the question as not sure what's best to do with showing you, the animations then stop.

Comment: Mmmh, could you show us at least parts of the html generated ?

Comment: Problem solved - didn't realise I needed extra code to fully transform xsl to html